# Retrieve Parse.com data In Parse.com Database without using the objectID

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parse-platform

Hi I Am Trying To Retrieve 2 Data From Parse.com Data Base Without The Object ID to My Combo Box But Just The Column Name. I Was Wondering Is It Possible To Be Done As Till Now I Only Manage To Retrieve Data Using The ObjectID

This Is My Code Before Using Parse.com:

```
        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM bindata  ";
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connect);


            connect.Open();
           reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string sName = reader.GetString("binLocation");
                cbSelectArea.Items.Add(sName);
            }
```

This Is My Code After I Try To Convert To Parse.com

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("IrinBin");
        ParseObject getIrisBin = await query.GetAsync("DNxL2nfe4k");
        tbMaxVolume.Text = getIrisBin.Get<int>("binHeight").ToString();
        cbSelectArea.Text = getIrisBin.Get<string>("binLocation");
```

It Will Only Pass In One Location At One Time Due The The Object ID. I Wanted The Data That Is Store In Column Name "binLocation"  To Be Pass To The cbSelectArea.text  So That When User Select The Location The Volume Of That Location Will Be Store Into tbMaxVolume.Text